# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of при генерации большого файла из Joomla 1.5.x

Tags: php, joomla, память, веб-сервер

Есть древний сайт-каталог с большим количеством товаров на Joomla 1.5.х
Попросили прикрутить генерацию YML-файла по всему каталогу, сделал:

```html
 function updateYML()
    {
        $cbr = file_get_contents('http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=' . date('d/m/Y'));
        preg_match('|<CharCode>USD</CharCode>.*?<Value>(.*?)</Value>|is', $cbr, $buff);
        $_usd = trim($buff[1]);
        
        $this->db->setQuery("SELECT id, parent_id, name FROM #categories ORDER BY `parent_id` ASC, `ordering` DESC, `id` DESC");
        $categories = $this->db->loadAssocList();
        
        $this->db->setQuery("SELECT id, category_id, name, description, params FROM #products ORDER BY `category_id` ASC, `ordering` DESC, `id` DESC");
        $products = $this->db->loadAssocList();
        
        $this->db->setQuery("SELECT id, name FROM #groups");
        $_groupsItems = $this->db->loadAssocList();
        if (count($_groupsItems)) {
            foreach ($_groupsItems as $_groupItem) {
                $groups[$_groupItem['id']] = $_groupItem['name'];
            }
        }
        unset($_groupsItems);
        
        $this->db->setQuery("SELECT element_id, file FROM #images ORDER BY `vid1`, `ordering`, `id` DESC");
        $rows = $this->db->loadAssocList();
        if (count($rows)) {
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                $images[$row['element_id']][] = "/images/{$row['element_id']}/b/{$row['file']}";
            }
        }
        unset($rows);        
        
        ob_start();
        require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'views'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'yml'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'yml.php');
        $yml = ob_get_contents();
        ob_clean();
        @unlink(JPATH_ROOT.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'tmp'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'export.yml');
        file_put_contents(JPATH_ROOT.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'tmp'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'export.yml', $yml);
    }
```

В итоге на виртуальном хостинге получаю:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 9080814 bytes) in ..... on line 182

Ругается на строчку:

> file_put_contents(JPATH_ROOT.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'tmp'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'export.yml',
>   $yml);

это так много команда file_put_contents жрет? 
Или у меня переменная $yml получилась слишком большая?

как еще можно уменьшить использование памяти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, так жрет команда `file_put_contents`. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713014/file-put-contents-and-file-get-contents-exhaust-memory-size) предлагают использовать комбинацию `fopen`/`fwrite`, чтобы не тратить память на удобные обертки.